# Empty entries will be worth 0 in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I need a solution from my code where I want if the entry in (le) will be 0 (integer 0) when the user doesn't enter anything

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
def tampil():
  le1=le.get()
  if le.get()=='':
    le1=0
  le2=int(le1)+1
  messagebox.showinfo("hasil",le2)
main=Tk()
main.title("Pangkat 2")
le=Entry(main)
le.pack()
bt=Button(main, text='klik',command=tampil)
bt.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem: what happens, what exactly should happen?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I think it is pretty clear that they want to display a 0 in the messagebox if nothing is entered in the entry. anywyas, the issue in that case could easily be solved by using an `else` clause and using `le2 = 0` in the `if` block

Comment: `le2 = int(le1)+1 if le1 != '' else 0`.  It is just simple if/else decision.

Comment: @acw1668 interestingly it seems that `0` as an integer doesn't get displayed on the messagebox as anything, it should be a string: `'0'`, also could use the walrus operator (3.8+) for assignment of `le2` in one line but no need

Comment: @Matiiss Sorry I don't understand what you say. Can you write a complete code for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if/else` to set the value of `le2`:

```py
def tampil():
  le1 = le.get()
  if le1 == '':
    le2 = '0' # as @Matiiss said in the comment, '0' should be used
  else:
    le2 = int(le1)+1
  messagebox.showinfo("hasil", le2)
```

However I would suggest to use `try/except` to cater invalid input as well:

```py
def tampil():
    try:
        le2 = int(le.get()) + 1
    except ValueError:
        # inalid input
        le2 = 0
    # use str(le2) to cater value 0 not shown issue
    messagebox.showinfo("hasil", str(le2))
```